# Weird as.POSIXct behavior depending on daylight savings time

Tags: r, posixct

It seems there is a bug in as.POSIXct. Or what is going on?

```
as.POSIXct("27/03/2006 02:05:38", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") 
[1] "2006-03-27 02:05:38 CEST"

as.POSIXct("26/03/2006 02:05:38", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
[1] NA
```

March 26, 2006 happened as far as I know...

Comment: Ahh, might be summertime

Comment: It is summertime. Check [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/germany?year=2006)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want it printed with the times you can always do.

```
as.POSIXct("26/03/2006 02:05:38", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2006-03-26 02:05:38 UTC"
```

Just make sure you do this for all conversions for consistency.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) states:

> UTC does not change with a change of seasons, but local time or civil
>   time may change if a time zone jurisdiction observes daylight saving
>   time (summer time). For example, local time on the east coast of the
>   United States is five hours behind UTC during winter, but four hours
>   behind while daylight saving is observed there.