# PosixCT conversion in R fails

Tags: r, posixct

I'm not sure why the following fails:

```
as.POSIXct("11MAR18:02:00:00",format="%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S")
```

If I try a different date it works fine:

```
as.POSIXct("10MAR18:02:00:00",format="%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S")
```

Solution:
**That hour doesn't exist due to daylight savings time!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. It works just fine:

```
as.POSIXct("11MAR18:02:00:00",format="%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2018-03-11 02:00:00 AEDT"

as.POSIXct("10MAR18:02:00:00",format="%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2018-03-10 02:00:00 AEDT"
```

This is also works with a different time zone, e.g. `tz = "UTC"`.

If this is not what you're after, can you please clarify?

Comment: Set the time zone to pacific.

Comment: @user1357015 Still works with `as.POSIXct("11MAR18:02:00:00",format="%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S", tz = "Pacific/Easter")`

Comment: This exact string fails for me: ```as.POSIXct("11MAR18:02:00:00",format="%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S", tz = "America/Los_Angeles")```

Comment: @user1357015 Confirmed. Indeed it's related to daylight savings. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116692/weird-as-posixct-behavior-depending-on-daylight-savings-time) and [this post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/POSIXlt-and-daylight-savings-time-td4642253.html) for similar examples.